# Using google groups to support commercial web site

Tags: google-groups

I'd like to provide support for users of my commercial web site. Because there are used google accounts for user authentication, it is logical to choose some tool which also supports google accounts. I think that Google Groups would fit perfectly my requirements. But after spending an hour trying to find that information I've got nothing.

Do you know if such use of Google Groups is allowed?